# Build two similar apps from one project

Tags: ios, project, fork

I have a project for a iOS app and wan't to make two different apps from it. I want the apps to have different skins and want the two apps to connect to two different web services. So I want a base app project from which I can select which to build.

I essentially want to fork a project but don't want to maintain two projects

Also they have to be able to be installed on the same device at the same time.

Is there some sort of "good practice advice" on how to do this?

I would also be interested in a similar solution for android projects

Comment: make workspace and you can add projects.

Comment: or one project with different targets

Comment: Workspaces and targets are intended precisely for this purpose. Google that :)

Answer (score 0):

A project with different targets will do:

[image: multiple targets]

They will allow you to set different Info.plist for each target (which allow you to set different bundle ID, allowing two apps installed at the same device).

[image: Info.plist file]

It also allows you to set C flags for each target (which allows you to put conditional statements based on the flag in your codes)

[image: C Flags]

You can have the lines that should be executed in the target, in this example the copy target, with ifdef macro:

```
#ifdef COPY_VER
     //lines of code to be executed for the copy target
#else
     //lines of code to be executed for the other target(s)
#endif
```